# Why is the php service missing after installing php on ubuntu?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

Just installed a clean copy of ubuntu and php (to start a wordpress blog)

As recommended [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-3-install-php), I installed php with

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
```

Which worked great. I can even confirm that PHP v7.0.22 is installed -

```
> php --version
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

I made some changes to Nginx in order to get it to read PHP files, and I'm trying to restart the php service -

```
> sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: Unit php7.0-fpm.service not found.
```

- which it's claiming is not found.

In fact, it looks like there is no service at all with a name like "php" installed when I run `sudo service --status-all` to list everything.

Do I have to do something extra to install the PHP service?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't install `php-fpm`. By the way, why did you install `libapache2-mod-php` if you're using nginx?

Comment: Ack, so simple. Good point on the apache package! I had just copied from the article I linked, and that article chose to use apache. I didn't catch that, thanks :)